# Would it be useful to allow Meta duplicates after a certain amount of time?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, meta

Regarding the main Ask Ubuntu site, there are two Meta questions here that I found that mention "time" and "duplicates":

- Primarily:  [Would it be useful to allow duplicates after x time?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9056/1165986)
- (To a much lesser extent): [Does time get considered in deciding Duplicate Questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13712/1165986).  While it's more about two questions that were asked nearly simultaneously, @Oli's answer mentions:

  > If there is a lot of time between the questions, it may also be worth considering that they are different issues and closing the new one may not be appropriate.

But I couldn't find a Meta question where the same topic had been covered for Ask Ubuntu *Meta* questions.

The site has been around for nearly 12 years now, and community (and even individual) opinions can change during that time, sometimes quite a bit.  Would it make sense to allow some older questions to be asked again for updated opinions and discussion without fear of them being closed as duplicates?  I think we should always link back to the older discussion (either the OP or someone via edit), but it seems that it would be nice at times to have a "clean slate" discussion, even if the outcome ends up the same.

Comment: TBH, I think it depends. For example, [this question by me](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19894/is-translating-posts-using-google-translate-acceptable) was helpful to ask again - I wanted to get clarity on a policy, and the policy was updated. In contrast, [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18973) it wouldn't be helpful to have dupes of, if there is a new argument, yes, re-asking is fine. But for support questions questions, for example, it isn't helpful.

Comment: I think it would be fine if it's a situation where you feel the circumstances may be different now than when the question was originally posted.  IMO just link to the other question and give an explanation why you think it's good to reopen discussion rather than add to the existing one.

Comment: Ubuntu changes fast enough that there are really very few actual duplicate questions. People deserve fresh answers. Sending someone to a "duplicated" question from 2010 whose answers are no loner valid is doing nobody any favors. This site should help people not frustrate them.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron this post is about questions on meta though. Not about the ones on the main site.